# Drag&Droping/Pasting video into program with CLI

Tags: linux, xorg, drag-and-drop, mime-types

I have script that records a video and saves it into a folder. What I want to do is to have an automated way to share recorded videos with friends - either by sending it via discord or caprine (fb messenger client).

If my script operated on images, I could simply copy it with mime type, like `xclip -t image/png path/to/picture.png`. When I do this, I can paste the image immediatelly into discord/caprine and it is interpreted as an image and gets sent.

However, this doesn't work with videos for some reason (I found the mime types [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)). Is there a way to either set the mime type to something so that discord/caprine correctly interprets it, or programatically drag&drop it?

When I take the video from file manager and manually drag it to discord/caprine, everything works without issues. Is there a way to do this via CLI?

Even things to look for would help a lot, I have no idea how this is called and what should I search for.

Comment: Note: one can easily and reliably detect file mimetype with `file -i filename`. Much better than hunting the correct mime type on the web.